# 'pip install Module' Program with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling, pip, progress-bar

**How to display console error messages in the program?**

I made a program with *tkinter* that installs python modules with Pip by simply writing the module's name.
But the problem is that I can only display an error message when someone doesn't write anything, not for example, when a module is already installed or doesn't exist. I would like to have these error messages so that every time there's an error on a normal console it appears in my program.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x360')
window.title('Pip Module Installer')
window.configure(bg='Light Grey')
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# TITLE: PIP MODULE INSTALLER
welcome = Label(window, text='Pip Module Installer', fg='Dark Blue', bg='Light Grey', font=('Calibri', 15))
welcome.grid(row=0, column=0)
# TEXT: INTRODUCTION
introduction = Label(window,
                     text='This program allows you to install any Pip Module in an easy way!\n',
                     fg='Black', bg='Light Grey', font=('Calibri', 13))
introduction.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20)

# FRAME: INSTRUCTIONS
group = LabelFrame(window, bg='Light Grey', bd=0,
                   highlightcolor='Dark Blue', highlightthickness=1.25)
group.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=15, pady=10)
# TITLE: INSTRUCTIONS
label_title = Label(group, text='Instructions',
                    fg='Dark Blue', bg='Light Grey', font=('Calibri', 14))
label_title.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='W', padx=10)
# TEXT: INSTRUCTIONS
instructions = Label(group, text='1. Type the name of the module, below:',
                     bg='Light Grey', font=('Calibri', 13))
instructions.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=(0, 10))


def module_installer():
    if module_input.get():
        user_input = module_input.get()
        os.system('pip install ' + user_input)
        response = 'Installation done'
    else:
        response = 'ERROR: Please type the name of the module'

    response_label = Label(window, text='', bg='Light Grey', font=('Calibri', 13))
    response_label.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=15, pady=(6, 0))
    response_label.config(text=response)
    module_input.delete(0, END)


# INPUT
module_input = Entry(group)
module_input.focus()
module_input.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=25)
# TEXT: INSTRUCTIONS
instructions = Label(group, text='2. Click ',
                     bg='Light Grey', font=('Calibri', 13))
instructions.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='W', padx=10, pady=(30, 15))
# INSTALL BUTTON
install_button = Button(group, text='Install', font=('Calibri', 13), command=module_installer)
install_button.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='W', padx=(69, 0), pady=(30, 15))
# TEXT: INSTRUCTIONS
instructions = Label(group,
                     text='3. The program will do the rest',
                     bg='Light Grey', font=('Calibri', 13))
instructions.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='NW', padx=10, pady=(0, 8))

#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop()
```

Also if you have other things to improve thank you in advance! It's my first Tkinter GUI program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.system` and use a `Text` widget to show the console output.

First create the `Text` box below `group` (`LabelFrame`):

```py
# output log
output_log = Text(window, width=60, height=10, state='disabled')
output_log.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=(0,10))
```

Then update `module_installer()` function as below:

```py
import sys
import subprocess as subp

...

def module_installer():
    user_input = module_input.get().strip()
    if user_input:
        # better use the same Python that runs this script, so use sys.executable
        proc = subp.Popen([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', user_input], stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE)
        # get the console output and errors
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
        if proc.returncode == 0:
            # pip returns 0
            response = stdout.decode()
        else:
            # there are errors
            response = stderr.decode()
    else:
        response = 'ERROR: Please type the name of the module'

    # show the response in the output box
    output_log['state'] = 'normal'
    output_log.replace('1.0', 'end', response)
    output_log['state'] = 'disabled'
    # clear user input
    module_input.delete(0, END)
```

*Note that you need to remove `window.geometry('500x360')` or adjust the window size to show all the `Text` box.*

Comment: How do I code it so that the Text Widget appears only after pressing the button 'Install'?

Comment: You don't call `grid(...)` after creation, but call it inside `module_installer()`.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system()` is probably not what you want in this case. It runs a specific command in the foreground terminal and your program will output the stderr contents if the given command fails.
For Example:

```
import os
os.system("rm /my/nice/folder")
print("Folder deleted") # this gets executed, no matter if the folder exists or if the user lacks permissions etc.
```

This will print

```
rm: cannot remove '/my/nice/folder': No such file or directory
256
Folder deleted
```

and "doesn't look very nice"

I highly reccomend using [pexpect](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/) since you can just ask for the return code (if a command was run sucessfully or witht an error) and handle the error seperately. Plus: You may even handle interactive commands like `passwd`, where the command prompts you to enter a specific argument (don't do it with `passwd` though for security reasons!)

In your program: What happens if the user misspells a module name? Say for example `numppy` instead of `numpy`?
Your program would execute the command, the console would fill up with error messages and the program would continue as if the module had been installed sucessfully.

By using a module like pexpect, you can handle such situations like follows:

```
from pexpect import spawn

module = "numpyyy"

cmd = spawn(f"pip install {module}")
print(f"Installing {module}...") # show waiting screen here
cmd.wait()  # wait for the process to finish

rc = cmd.exitstatus  # check for the command's return-code
if rc == 0:
    print(f"{module} sucessfully installed")
else:
    # display your error message here
    print(f"There was an error while installing {module}:")
    cmd.read()  # print the whole output of your command
```

If you found my suggestion helpful, please leave me an UP,
If you have further questions, just leave a comment below :)

Comment: I installed Pespect and tried the code above but it gives me this error: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/CODING/python/correction.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pexpect import spawn
ImportError: cannot import name 'spawn' from 'pexpect' (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pexpect\__init__.py)`